# Convert lactose in milk to Galactooligosaccharides

Tags: enzymes

There are few articles describing the conversion of lactose to GOS on Wiley Online Library with different enzymes. Yet none of them really talks about what % of the lactose in milk can be converted to GOS.

Is it possible to convert all lactose to GOS, and still be able to consume the milk/dairy product?

Comment: It may help to link the articles you have already read through, just so answers don't have to search through the same articles.